# How do I access the original file name that is associated a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, file-extension

I have created my own file extension and associated that file extension with a batch file, that is simply suppose to call a ruby script. So the ruby script will execute and modify the original file (Test.jim). However I need to pass the name of the original file to the ruby script so it can access it. My batch file is simply

```
ruby batrun.rb %0
```

However this passes the name/path of the batch file not the original file with my file extension. How can I pass this through the batch file.

*EDIT

As asked for this is how I associate my file extension with the batch file

```
Ftype jimfile="C:\Users\Server\Desktop\File Extension\Jimbat.bat" "%1"
Assoc .jim=jimfile
```

I just put that in a batch file and then ran it.

Comment: please clarify how did you created association do you have a registry entry for ".jim" extension as  "something.bat %1". If so then  "Something.bat" would contain `@ruby batrun.rb %~nx1` to pass the unquoted file name to ruby command.

Comment: I have editted the question to show how I associated my file extension. Unforutantly using %~nx1 did not work.

Comment: `Ftype jimfile="C:\Users\Server\Desktop\File Extension\Jimbat.bat" "%1"` "I just put that in a batch file and then ran it.". Check `ftype jimfile` - probably it isn't what you think it is.

Comment: No its working properly in the way that it calls the correct executable to run when I click on Test.jim. Its just not passing the path to the original file (Test.jim) to the executable

Comment: it's either running properly OR not passing the parameter. Check the output of  `ftype jimfile`.

Comment: The output of ftype jimfile is `jimfile=C:\Users\Server\Desktop\File Extension\Jimbat.bat" ""`. So it is missing the %1 after the executable. I'm pretty inexperienced with batch files so I don't understand why it is not it is not there.

Comment: [You need to escape `%` in a batch script by doubling it `"%%1"`](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html).

Answer (score 0):

If anyone in interested I figure out how to fix it.
For some reason running the association through a batch file will NOT allow for the addition of parameters. I have absolutely no idea why, but simply typing the exact same thing

```
ftype jimfile="C:\Users\Server\Desktop\FileExtension\Jimbat.bat" %1
```

into a cmd with administrative access will work perfectly

Comment: write your batchfiel as `ftype jimfile="C:\Users\Server\Desktop\FileExtension\Jimbat.bat" %%1`

Answer (score 0):

Just a clarification the answer would be use these command at command prompt:

> ```
> Assoc .jim=jimfile
> Ftype jimfile="C:\Users\Server\Desktop\File Extension\Jimbat.bat" "%1" %*
> set PATHEXT=.jim;%PATHEXT%
> ```

but in a batch file:

> ```
> Assoc .jim=jimfile
> Ftype jimfile="C:\Users\Server\Desktop\File Extension\Jimbat.bat" "%%1" %%*
> set PATHEXT=.jim;%PATHEXT%
> ```

jimbat.bat contains:

> ```
> echo ruby batrun.rb %*
> ruby batrun.rb %*
> ```

Notes:

If you type `test.jim a b c` the command will be as if you typed `ruby batrun.rb "C:\Users\Server\Desktop\File Extension\test.jim" a b c` a quoted full path to `test.jim` (assuming same directory). Your last comments indicate you are now using double quotes. Using double quotes it typical when using batch file scripts with extension associations.  Look at `ftype` output you will see many programs do not use double quotes because of the way the handle command line arguments.

If you had wanted `ruby batrun.rb C:\Users\Server\Desktop\File Extension\test.jim a b c` the `ftype` would omit double quotes as indicated in `ftype /h`. You only need `%*` to allow for more than one argument otherwise `%1` is sufficient.

`assoc`, `ftype` goes to registry and applies to windows globally. I noticed when testing you can clear `assoc` from cmd.exe but `ftype`can only by removed using  registry tool not `ftype` command.